# How does AWS RDS perform replication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

AWS RDS offer Multi-AZ Deployments by replicating the data to stand by instances in other AZs. How is it done? Is it some sort of change data capture process like Goldengate or Datapump?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't public information.

Here's all we really know: it's synchronous.

> Multi-AZ deployments for the MySQL, Oracle, and PostgreSQL engines utilize **synchronous physical replication** to keep data on the standby up-to-date with the primary. Multi-AZ deployments for the SQL Server engine use **synchronous logical replication** to achieve the same result, employing SQL Server-native Mirroring technology. (Emphasis added.)
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/

So, depending on your platform, either "logical" or "physical" replication.

To me, "physical" replication sounds like low-level storage replication.

On that point, we know that RDS runs on EBS storage, and we know that EBS storage is always replicated -- though typically this only occurs within one availability zone -- but it may be that multi-AZ relies on an intimate relationship with EBS and cross-AZ storage replication that is hidden from view.

Or it may not.  All we know is that, other than for MS-SQL, the solution is not platform-native replication.

This information isn't documented.